# .jar file only works when used in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm using a .jar file which I imported to Eclipse, and when I used Eclipse to run the application is works just fine.

But when I try running it from the command line with just the command `java ClassName` I get a `NoClassDefFoundError` message.

The .jar file is in the same directory as the main class I need to run.

I tried using the classpath command in the terminal

```
java -classpath pack.jar ClassName
```

but I got the same error but this time it was in the main thread

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
```

Why does my program work in Eclipse but not on its own?

Comment: Are you sure the path(s) in the `-classpath` are correct ?

Comment: You need to include both the jar, and your own code, on the class path. Note it's helpful to include *what* class can't be found, so we know if it's your code, or library code.

Comment: Okay I see what you mean now, code below worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you'll need to use: `java -classpath .:pack.jar ClassName`.

Comment: This works, thanks. I've never seen the .: before, what is its purpose? I'm surprised I haven't seen anywhere though I've been trying to fix this for hours.

Comment: @ppepper: the dot means the current directory (that's where your main class is) and the colon separates entries in the classpath. `.:pack.jar` means 'put the current directory and pack.jar in the classpath.'

Answer (score 0):

`NoClassDefFoundError` will come if a class was present during compile time but not available in java classpath during runtime.

Its Not Even Close To Being equal to `ClassNotFoundException` n u mustn't confuse them together, so u need to include the whoe path of the .jar file,

use the previously explained technique to do so, or if it was a jar file that want use frequently without using the call to `java -classpath ..` thing try importing the file into the OS class path directory.